# How to get primary key column in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I need to get the name of the primary key column.

In the input, I only have the table name.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

Make sure that 'TABLE_NAME' is in upper case since Oracle stores table names in upper case.

Comment: Thanks, Richie. One more question: how to encode 'P' ? I need to execute this with "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE". thnx again.

Comment: I think you would just put two single quotes round it like this ''P''

Comment: Alternatively, you could [quote it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) using `q`.

Comment: and constraint_type = 'R' for foreign key

Comment: Worked for me when not having the schema prefix before the table! Thanks!

Comment: If you need this in order to DROP the CONSTRAINT, then also include this column in your select `cons.CONSTRAINT_NAME`

Comment: I get `invalid table name` error. (Where) do I need to prefix the schema in this code, if at all?

Comment: @richie What does it mean when you do not get anything back?

Answer (score 30):

Same as the answer from 'Richie' but a bit more concise.

1. Query for user constraints only

   ```
   SELECT column_name FROM all_cons_columns WHERE constraint_name = (
     SELECT constraint_name FROM user_constraints 
     WHERE UPPER(table_name) = UPPER('tableName') AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
   );
   ```
2. Query for all constraints

   ```
   SELECT column_name FROM all_cons_columns WHERE constraint_name = (
     SELECT constraint_name FROM all_constraints 
     WHERE UPPER(table_name) = UPPER('tableName') AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
   );
   ```

Comment: @FearlessFuture For me it worked well. Can you describe your problem a bit more expressive?

Comment: I don't get any results from this query, but I do get results from the query for the accepted answer.

Comment: @FearlessFuture I assume that the constraint you are searching for isn't a user constraint. Replace `user_constraints` by `all_constraints`.

Comment: This causes trouble if you have a table with the same name in two or more schemas - need to also include owner in the join:  `SELECT owner, column_name, position FROM all_cons_columns WHERE (owner, constraint_name) in (SELECT owner, constraint_name FROM all_constraints WHERE UPPER(table_name) = UPPER('&tableName') AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P') order by owner, position;`

Comment: @MarkStewart I aggree the second Query will not work. But your solution is inefficient. Try: "SELECT 
  cols.column_name AS KEY_STREAM, 
  '=' AS KEY_CONDITION,
  cols.column_name as KEY_LOOKUP,
  '' AS KEY_STREAM2
FROM user_constraints cons, user_cons_columns cols
WHERE cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
and cons.table_name = '<TABLE_NAME>'
and cons.table_name = cols.table_name;"

Comment: Why do I get tables with multiple primary keys, some of which are non-unique? I assume this is some very bad implementation of compound keys?

Comment: @MaileCup, you are working with a PK consisting of multiple columns (composite key), in order to identify a record uniquely. I wouldn't say that it's a bad practice, but my optinion is that it's much easier to work with technical generated IDs.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select constraint_name,constraint_type from user_constraints where table_name** **= ‘TABLE_NAME’ ;
```

(This will list the primary key and then)

```
Select column_name,position from user_cons_columns where constraint_name=’PK_XYZ’;
```

(This will give you the column, here PK_XYZ is the primay key name)

Answer (score 3):

Try This Code
Here I created a table for get primary key column in oracle which is called test and then query

```
create table test
(
id int,
name varchar2(20),
city varchar2(20),
phone int,
constraint pk_id_name_city primary key (id,name,city)
);

SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols WHERE cols.table_name = 'TEST' AND cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name AND cons.owner = cols.owner  ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the following script as something like findPK.sql.

```
set verify off
accept TABLE_NAME char prompt 'Table name>'

SELECT cols.column_name
FROM all_constraints cons NATURAL JOIN all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND table_name = UPPER('&TABLE_NAME');
```

It can then be called using

```
@findPK
```